# detecting only vertical lines in binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, hough-transform, houghlinesp, houghlines

I am processing some binary images where I would like to find the boundary lines of the binary images. So, as an example, here is an input image:

[image]

What I do is use edge detection and line detecting hough transform to get the borders from the image. So what i do is:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 200)
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho=1.0, theta=np.pi/180, threshold=2)
```

Now drawing these lines result in the following image:

[image]

However, what I want to do is etect only the vertical lines i.e. lines going "upwards" in the image. I think I have to manipulate the hough transform parameters but am unable to find the combination that returns only the vertical lines.

Comment: Try the sobel filter instead of the HoughTransform. https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html

Comment: after you detect those lines, just discard the horizontal ones

Comment: you can find the angle of lines and then subset with desired angle range.